# How do I rewrite a URL in IIS?

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

What would be simplest way to get this functionality in my website. A small example code will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of IIS what language/development tools?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provide a free URL rewriter you can install on IIS7:

> [IIS UrlRewrite (IIS.NET)](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)

There's even a nice video introduction to using it.